# Express : Post request, announce the result, and move the page 3 seconds later

Tags: html, node.js, express

Hi I'm practicing Express and developing and simple todo-app

When the user sends POST for form data, the success screen appears and I want to implement the function of going to the main page after 3 seconds

first of

here is my server.js

```
app.post('/add', (요청, 응답) => {
    
    ..Roughly storing data in db...

    응답.send(`<div style = "text-align : center; margin-top : 25%;">POST request Done!\ngoing to main-page after 3s..</div>`);
})
```

I thought the initial plan would be simple if I put up a notice and ran setTimeout in 3 seconds with [res.sendFile(__dirname + '/html/index.html')] at the bottom.
However, after a failed search, we found that [res.send] was executed only once, and subsequent scripts were ignored.

So I thought of it as a way to show the notice and the main page html in one send statement, but I can't think of it.